# No data in Simple SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services Cube (Analytics Accelerator for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0)

Tags: dynamics-crm, analytics, dynamics-crm-4, cube, accelerator

I installed, deployed & processed the cube on my CRM system as discussed in the documentation.  At no point in this process do I receive any error.  From within the Visual Studio Microsoft CRM MSCRM data source view, I can open the tables & run the queries to see data.  The problem arises when I try to browse the cube. I have plenty of data in my CRM system. Sorry if I’m missing the obvious, but this is my first data cube. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it yet it sounds like your cube hasn't been processed. If any piece of it changes and you want these values to show you must reprocess and deploy. Likewise, if you just created the cube you have to process and deploy to your SSAS server to browse it through BIDS or SMS.